# How to change the bg color in this code? (designer trying to learn coding)

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, background-color

How to change the bg color in this code? (designer trying to learn coding)

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/fdefb19b/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/fdefb19b/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/fdefb19b/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/r16/Stats.min.js"></script>
<script>
var SEPARATION = 100, AMOUNTX = 50, AMOUNTY = 50;

            var container, stats;
            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var particles, particle, count = 0;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 1000;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                particles = new Array();

                var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
                var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {

                    color: 0xff0000,
                    program: function ( context ) {

                        context.beginPath();
                        context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
                        context.fill();

                    }

                } );

                var i = 0;

                for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {

                    for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {

                        particle = particles[ i ++ ] = new THREE.Sprite( material );
                        particle.position.x = ix * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTX * SEPARATION ) / 2 );
                        particle.position.z = iy * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTY * SEPARATION ) / 2 );
                        scene.add( particle );

                    }

                }

                renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            //

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
                mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;

            }

            function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

                if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                    mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                    mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

                }

            }

            function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

                if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                    mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                    mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

                }

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() {

                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                var i = 0;

                for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {

                    for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {

                        particle = particles[ i++ ];
                        particle.position.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 ) * 50 ) +
                            ( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) * 50 );
                        particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 ) + 1 ) * 4 +
                            ( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) + 1 ) * 4;

                    }

                }

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

                count += 0.1;

            }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In three.js you can set the scene background color:

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xff0000);
```

This is documented at
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/scenes/Scene.background.